# C#: Make Task run simultaneously

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I am trying to run Several Tasks continously, non-stop.
Here is my code:

```
int maxThread = 100;
Task[] tasks = new Task[maxThreads];
while(true)
{
   for(int i = 0;i<maxThreads;i++)
   {
     tasks[i] = new Task.Factory.StartNew(someTask);
   }
   Task.WaitAll(tasks);
}
```

So this function waits for all tasks to be completed and runs next batch of tasks. But I would like to start a task as soon as one is finished, without waiting for the other tasks.

Thanks!

Comment: @Ramhound , I think you are mistaken. tasks are in charge of managing their own threads. you should NOT start each task in a different thread.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use `SemaphoreSlim`

```
int maxThread = 100;
SemaphoreSlim sem = new SemaphoreSlim(maxThread);

while (true)
{
    sem.Wait();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(someTask)
                .ContinueWith(t => sem.Release());
}
```

Using `Parallel.ForEach` with `var po =  new ParallelOptions(){MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 100};` can be other alternative. But `Parallel.ForEach` doesn't guarantee it will use 100 Tasks for it.

Comment: @Capripio No, since the semaphore is used to limit the number of concurrent tasks to 100.

Comment: So can I write my like this:
    `int maxThread = 100;
    SemaphoreSlim sem = new SemaphoreSlim(maxThread);
    Task[] tasks = new Task[maxThreads];
while(true)
{
   for(int i = 0;i<maxThreads;i++)
   {
     tasks[i] = new Task.Factory.StartNew(someTask).ContinueWith(t => sem.Release());
   }
   Task.WaitAll(tasks);
}`

Comment: @Capripio No, there is no `sem.Wait`. What above code does is: it creates `100` tasks and whenever running tasks fall under 100, it creates a new task.

Comment: But its also work when all tasks get finish not soon after one task end!

Comment: @Capripio Sorry I don't understand.. If what you say is *it waits all tasks to finish to start new tasks*, No. It starts a new task as soon as one finishes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to use this one. Attach tasks to its parent; it is easy. Like this.

```
Task t1 = new Task(()=>{
    // put your children tasks here.
    Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{}, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
});

t1.RunSynchronously();

// then start your next batch tasks.
```

Comment: Why would a task start before all of its siblings ended in this solution?

Comment: He might have batchs short running tasks to run in orders.