# Preloading next IEnumerable<T> value

Tags: c#, .net, performance, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

Given the class structure:

```
public class Foo
{
    public IEnumerable<Bar> GetBars()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            yield return new Bar() { Name = i.ToString() };
        }
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have list of `IEnumerable<Foo>` and the time to retrieve the next `Bar` within the `GetBars()` method is quite slow (simulated above with `Thread.Sleep(1000)`).

I would like to do the following:

```
myFoo.AsParallel().SelectMany(foo => foo.GetBars().Select(bar => bar.Name))
```

But because of the delay I would like to continue to pre-load the next `Bar` value for each `Foo` and then have the `IEnumable<Bar>` for each `Foo` merged into each other in the order that they become accessable.

I have been looking into the Tpl Dataflow async nuget libary (specifically the `TransformBlock` and to a lesser extent `ActionBlock`) but can't find anything that helps me do what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, parallel or not, you still can't even start getting the second `Bar` object until you've gotten the first.  Using PLINQ only really helps if you're doing long running processing on each object through the LINQ functionality, not if the delay is due to the underlying `IEnumerable`.

One option is to return a sequence of `Task` objects, such that moving the iterator takes very little time:

```
public async Task<Bar> GenerateFoo()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return new Bar() { Name = i.ToString() };
}

public IEnumerable<Task<Bar>> GetBars()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        yield return GenerateFoo();
    }
}
```

Using that code means that just moving the iterator only *starts* the generation of `Bar`, rather than waiting until it completes.  Once you have that you can either add continuations to each task to handle the processing of each `Bar`, or you can use a method such as `Task.WaitAll` or `Task.WhenAll` to wait for them all to complete.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking into the [Reactive Extensions (Rx) Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx). It basically allows you to use LINQ on "push" type collections (`IObservable<T>`), instead of "pull" type collections (`IEnumerable<T>`). In other words, your code can react to new items in a collection as they become available.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how exactly would you use Rx here?

Answer (score 1):

You can write an extension method as below which will *yield* the bars(in any enumerable) as soon as they are available.

```
myFoo.Select(x=>x.GetBars()).Flatten().Select(bar => bar.Name)
```

---

```
public static class ParallelExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> enumOfEnums)
    {
        BlockingCollection<T> queue = new BlockingCollection<T>();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(enumOfEnums, e =>
            {
                foreach (var x in e)
                {
                    queue.Add(x);
                }
            });
            queue.CompleteAdding();
        });

        return queue.GetConsumingEnumerable();
    }
}
```

Comment: But this won't start enumerating all collections at the same time, because `Parallel.ForEach()` uses partitioning.

Comment: @svick Yes, It depends on the # of CPUs. I could have used something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16760965/1906557) to create many tasks but the answer would be more complicated

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing a new implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` which performed the prefectching:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    TaskFactory<T> taskFactory = new TaskFactory<T>();
    Task<T> task = null;
    IEnumerator<T> enumerator = Source.GetEnumerator();

    T result = null;
    do
    {
        if (task != null)
        {
            result = task.Result;
            if (result == null)
                break;
        }

        task = taskFactory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                return enumerator.Current;
            else
                return null;
        });
        if (result != null)
            yield return result;
    }
    while (task != null);
}
```

It simply requests the first two results before returning the first result and then keeps always one result request ahead of what has been yield.

Comment: This doesn't actually prefetch anything, because you start the `Task` only after execution of this method resumes after `yield return`.

Comment: @svick I copy paste failed.. fixed now.