# Control number of threads

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application which i am add files to my `Listbox` and run those files.
My application play this files using `PcapDot.Net` project DLLs and send the packets through the network adapter.
The way is very simple: after all the files added to my application `Listbox` and the play button clicked the application handle the first file and after this file finished the next file began.
what i want to do is add control to my GUI that control the number of open thread in order to have the ability to play several file simultaneous.

This is my play button event:

```
private BackgroundWorker bw;

    private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new               RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
        manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        if (bw.IsBusy != true)
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listBoxFiles.Items.Counti++) //run in loop all over my listbox
{
           // here if have several wiresharkFile events that update my UI:
        wiresharkFile.statusChangedEvent += new WiresharkFile.StatusChangedDelegate(
            (wFile) =>
            {
                bw.ReportProgress(wiresharkFile.packetProgressPrecentage, wiresharkFile);
            });

       wiresharkFile.sendBuffer(); //play the file
}
    }
```

What is the best way to add option to open more than 1 thread in the same time ?

Comment: are you asking how to open a thread? cus' if not please explain what are you asking

Comment: Make this code work first.  It will then also be obvious how to get what you are asking for.

Comment: This code works fine, i only ask what is the best option to open simultaneous several threads, for example if i have list of 10 files and i only want 4 files at the same time so after 1 of the first files finish and i have now 3 files at the same time so automatically another file will start (maybe with Task ??)

Comment: @user2214609 maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/16760965/932418 ?

Comment: Can i have an example how should I put this code in my code (i am a new developer...)

Comment: @user2214609 was the example as you needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a simple example for your use, it shows how to create and sign to an event you'll pop when the thread that open a file ends and then you can, when the event pop, to open another file. make sure you keep a counter and a lock so you won't have race conditions

```
   public delegate void FileClosedHndlr();


   public class MyThread
   {
      private event FileClosedHndlr FileClosed;

      public void MyMain()
      {
         Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(start));
         FileClosed += new FileClosedHndlr(MyThread_FileClosed);
         t.Start();
      }

      void MyThread_FileClosed()
      {
         // Thread has ended file open
         // open another file
      }

      private void start()
      {
         // Open the file
         // End thread

         if (FileClosed != null)
         {
            FileClosed();
         }
      }
   }
```

it took me a while, so use it